J! : After upgrade to 5.76.2 from 5.75, system reports can't file 'required' administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Cart/DAO/Cart.php'
Running on Joomla 4.4.8, PHP 8.1.29
After upgrade to v5.76.2 from a running v5.73 installation, performed the DB update fine, the system gave the successful update page, and so I clicked on the link to see the system status.   It looked fine, other than the Smarty Form check notice about changing that to false.
Then tried to go to the main CiviCRM dashboard, and got this error:
An error has occurred.
0 Failed opening required '/home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Cart/DAO/Cart.php' (include_path='/home/usafnu5/public_html/media/civicrm/ext/ca.civicrm.logviewer/:/home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/ext/scheduled_communications/:/home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/ext/civicrm_admin_ui/:/home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/ext/civicrm_search_ui/:/home/usafnu5/public_html/media/civicrm/ext/ckeditor5/:/home/usafnu5/public_html/media/civicrm/ext/uk.org.futurefirst.networks.emailamender/:/home/usafnu5/public_html/media/civicrm/ext/org.wikimedia.rip/:/home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/ext/afform/core/:/home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/ext/authx/:/home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/ext/flexmailer/:/home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/ext/search_kit/:/home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/ext/legacycustomsearches/:/home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/ext/ckeditor4/:/home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/ext/recaptcha/:/home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/ext/greenwich/:/home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/ext/eventcart/:/home/usafnu5/public_html/media/civicrm/ext/net.ourpowerbase.sumfields/:/home/usafnu5/public_html/media/civicrm/ext/eu.tttp.noverwrite/:.:/home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm:/home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages:/home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/tecnickcom:/home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/auth_sasl:/home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear_exception:/home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/console_getopt:/home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src:/home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db:/home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/log:/home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/mail:/home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/mail_mime:/home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/net_socket:/home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/net_smtp:/home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/validate_finance_creditcard:.:/home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/:/home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm//packages:.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php81/root/usr/share/pear') 
--------------

Part of the issue is that the path listed for the file, does not exist; there is no Cart directory under the Event directory.
Not sure if a file did not get updated, or I messed up on the upgrade and should not have skipped 5.76.0 and 5.76.1, but I've done that in the past as the changes were cumulative.
Any advice would be appreciated, as my website is down for the count.
Thanks,
Neil

The site might come back up if you force-enable the eventcart extension, and then you can decide what to do after.
UPDATE civicrm_extension set is_active = 1 WHERE full_name='eventcart';

Thanks ... before I saw this, I restored my site back to last night's backup, then installed 5.75.2 files, then 5.76.2 and ran the DB update.     It ran fine, then when I checked the system status, it informed me about certain directories that needed deletion.
I renamed the directories to be on the safe side, and everything worked.
I did check the table after I read your comment, and saw that eventcart was set to active now.
All is well, thanks for the advice.
